# Global variable or Static class for Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I'm developing an Android app with Kotlin.

For example I have an access token which I get on my LoginActivity and I need this access token on each activity to call API. I know that I could use putExtra() and getExtra(), but it doesn't make sense to write this code for each new activity.

Is there a way to create a global variable or something like static class which will be accessible for all activities in app?

What is the right Android approach for that?

Comment: If you define a property outside of any class, it is the equivalent of `static` in other languages. You can optionally define a property inside a named `object` or `companion object` if you like for code organization purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences.
After successfully login store the access key to shared preferences and use that access key from shared preferences everywhere in the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple class.

```
public class Important{
   private static String key = "";
   public static void setKey(String key){
       this.key = key;
   }
   public static String getKey(){
       return key;
   }
}
```

Create this class under in your package. When you get your key just call `Important.setKey("key")`. Then you can get your key anytime anywhere by calling `Important.getKey()`

Comment: This is Java, and I think it doesn't compile because you didn't make the `key` field static

Comment: The question is tagged Kotlin, though

Answer (score 0):

I think an `object` or `companion object` is [what you are looking for.](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/objects)

Be warned is is possible for variables in the `object` to be garbage collected without your control. I would recommend creating a BaseActivity class that all your Activities inherit from and override the following methods.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    savedInstanceState?.let {
        MyObject.refreshFromBundle(it)
    }
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    MyObject.populateBundle(outState)
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
```

Then in your `object` have the following functions

```
fun refreshFromBundle(bundle: Bundle) {
    // Get info from bundle and populate your variables
}

fun populateBundle(bundle: Bundle) {
    // Put info from variables into the bundle
}
```

More info on why it is necessary [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Edit: Cleared up my language thanks to @Tenfour04 below

Comment: Not sure if that's what you mean, but Kotlin `object`s are never garbage collected under any circumstances barring some very specific destructive use of Java reflection.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Interesting. Could you provide a source please? I ask because I was getting a crash where a variable that was set inside an `object` was null when it shouldn't have been. Implementing my changes above fixed that.

Comment: It's maybe not completely clear [in the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#object-declarations-overview), but `object`s are singletons, so it would be a completely broken implementation of a singleton if they could be cleared from memory. But now you seem to be talking about properties inside the `object`, not the `object` itself.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Correct. It was properties inside the object that where being cleared not the `object` itself. Is there anywhere that says the properties of a singleton can't be garbage collected?

Comment: No, they of course can be garbage collected if you change them back to null. But otherwise, an `object` is just like any other class. Properties are never nulled-out and garbage collected randomly. That would be such a ridiculous behavior for a programming language that I can't imagine any documentation for any programming language would bother to specifically say that it *doesn't* do that.